# Cross Database Queries vs Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-replication, database-administration

I have 2 SQL 2008 database servers that have database stored procedures with cross database server queries (different physical servers. querying done through linked servers). I'm assuming this is not best practice so I want to figure out a way to fix this. I thought about replication but our database design prevents that (Some tables do not have primary keys).

Is there any other options I have to not have to do cross server queries?

The problem is that not all the databases on server A are on server B.

Answer (score 1):

SymmetricDS can replication SQL Server (Express, Standard, or Enterprise).  You do not need to have PKs on all your tables.  It will use all columns for tables without primary keys or you have the ability to provide virtual keys to use for replication.

[SymmetricDS Overview](http://www.jumpmind.com/products/symmetricds/overview)